# Refresh DataGridView using BindingSource and TableAdapter

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, datasource

i actually work on a Customer-DataGrid but i stuck on the Sources because i dont use really often C#.

I have a DataGridView (dataGridView1), a internal Database (Database.mdf), a BindingSource (customerBindingSource) and customerTableAdapter

Now i trying to refresh the DataSource when i click a button.
Here is a simple snippet:

```
    private void Kundenverwaltung_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'kundenAnsicht.customer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.kundenAnsicht.customer);
    }

    // I tried already some methods but i dont find a properly, functionally way
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.kundenAnsicht.customer);
    }
```

I hope you can understand my problem.
~ Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your DataGridView with "customerBindingSource":

```
`private void Kundenverwaltung_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.customerBindingSource;
    this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.kundenAnsicht.customer);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.kundenAnsicht.customer);
}`
```

It all.